# A new animated icon that turns from a tick to an "X"?

Tags: user-interface, flutter, dart

Hello I have a question for you, I have not yet found a solution for on the Internet.
I would like an AnimatedIcon that turns from a tick to an "X" for close.
But unfortunately the selection of animated icons is very small.
Is there a way to create your own AnimatedIcons?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do the morphing between 2 svg images(tick & X), convert to path, then use path_morph library, see [Path Morph](https://blog.bam.tech/developer-news/path-morphing-from-figma-to-flutter-app)